# Serialize model that inherits from ObservableObject

Tags: c#, serialization, mvvm-light

I want to serialize and deserialize a model object that inherits from `MvvmLight.ObservableObject`. Trying to deserialize the object with `System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer.ReadObject` throws a `System.Runtime.Serialization.InvalidDataContractException` with the info that the base class (i.e. `MvvmLight.ObservableObject`) doensn't have the `DataContractAttribute` or `SerializableAttribute`. My model that don't work looks like that:

```
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight;

[DataContract]
public class MyModel : ObservableObject
{
  [IgnoreDataMember]
  private int _id;
  [DataMember]
  public int Id
  {
      get => _id;
      set => Set(ref _id, value);
  }
}
```

After removing `[DataContract]` there's no exception but also no deserialized data.

A solution could be to create a copy of `MyModel` called `MyModelSerializable` with the same properties but that don't inherit from ObservableObject and use that for serializing. After deserializing, the `MyModel` objects could be created with the data of the `MyModelSerializable` objects. Is there a better solution?

Edit: As requested a link to the code of `GalaSoft.MvvmLight.ObservableObject`: https://github.com/lbugnion/mvvmlight/blob/master/GalaSoft.MvvmLight/GalaSoft.MvvmLight%20(PCL)/ObservableObject.cs

Comment: can you please update the definition of 'ObservableObject'

Comment: this error means you have unknow types to finish the serialization, so could you  show the code of ObservableObject ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MVVMLight and Data Serialisation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14245569/mvvmlight-and-data-serialisation)

Answer (score 0):

You cant use DataContract Attribute here if you cant mark the ObservableObject with DataContract. SO in your case i think you couldnt mark the ObservableObject.

You have to Create another Class with the desired items you want to serialize without class derived ObservableObject

Maybe You could implement (in another Serialized Class with DataContract Attribute which sees  MyModel) in your project:

```
    [OnSerializing]
    void PrepareForSerialization(StreamingContext sc)
    {
        //get items from MyModel and inject in new class serializable
    }
```

Comment: That looks like a possible solution, thanks. I solved it now by not using `System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer`, but the json serializer Json.Net by Newtonsoft, it works with classes that inherit from ObservableObject.